# How to check CheckBoxList checked values exist in GridView asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I want to display asp CheckBoxList checked items text in gridview row by row.This is my code , It adding list items text to gridview row by row, but when I checked items it duplicate same Item text again and again in gridview . How I checked Is exist same Item text in Gridview please help me .
This is my checked event

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // check view state is not null  
        if (ViewState["MailTracking"] != null)
        {
            //get datatable from view state   
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["MailTracking"];
            // DataRow oItem = null;
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {


                foreach (ListItem li1 in CheckBoxListBranch.Items)
                {
                    if (li1.Selected)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(li1.Text);
                    }

                }


                //Remove initial blank row  
                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dt.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dt.AcceptChanges();

                }
                // dt.Rows.Add(oItem);
                ViewState["MailTracking"] = dt;
                GVDisplay.DataSource = dt;
                GVDisplay.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be appending to the already existing list every time an item is checked. I would create a new DataTable every time (especially if it is a small list).

Example:

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable(); // Assuming that dt is a local variable
    foreach (ListItem li1 in CheckBoxListBranch.Items)
    {
        if (li1.Selected)
            dt.Rows.Add(li1.Text);

    }
    GVDisplay.DataSource = dt;
    GVDisplay.DataBind();
}
```